# Use of "this" when a class contains a nested static class

Tags: java, static, linked-list, nested-class

I was going through the following code which is a linked-list implementation using a static nested class:

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/code/LinkedList.java

One line I wasn't able to comprehend was:

```
 public boolean contains(AnyType x)
   {
      **for(AnyType tmp : this)**
         if(tmp.equals(x)) return true;

      return false;
   }
```

How's it that "this" here allows us to traverse the data that's stored inside each Node?

Comment: `this` is the LinkedList. And it's Iterable. So you can use the foreach loop to iterate over its elements.

Comment: The method is declared in the LinkedList, so `this` refers to the LinkedList.

Answer (score 1):

Because `this` in this case is an `Iterable` (more specifically, a `LinkedList`).

The [`for-each`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop introduced in Java 5, is syntactic sugar for calling the `Iterator` of the `Iterable`. In your example case, the code is equivalent with

```
for (Iterator<AnyType> i = this.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    if (i.next().equals(x)) return true;
}
```